# Cómo evitar que una aplicación se ejecute varias veces?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Me preguntaba cómo podía hacer para que si esta iniciado el programa no se pueda iniciar otra instancia. Vi un ejemplo de c# por el foro pero ninguno para python. Podrian ayudarme?. Pd: Se trata de un juego en pygame por si sirve de algo.

Comment: Un truco típico suele ser que al arrancar crees un fichero temporal y al terminar lo borres. Si intentas arrancar una nueva instancia y ésta detecta que el fichero ya existe, emite un error del estilo "Ya hay otra instancia en ejecución". A menudo también se añade la coletilla "Si no fuera así, borra el fichero X e intenta de nuevo" (para contemplar el posible caso en el que una instancia anterior haya terminado anormalmente sin poder borrar el fichero)

Comment: fíjate este hilo recomiendan una librería https://stackoverflow.com/a/1265445/1423096